# LPAD Function did not insert zeros from start

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 3 columns with values like:

```
projectid     disttid     cardno
 6              3          17422117
```

I want merge these 3 columns into 1 column like:

```
projectid     disttid     cardno         new_column
 6              3          17422117       00600317422117
```

I tried with this query but LPAD function did not insert 2 zeros from start

```
select LPAD(projectid,3,'0')||LPAD(disttid,3,'0')||max(cardno)+1 "NEW_URN"
from we_group_hof_k 
where urn like '006%'
group by projectid,disttid;
```

This query gives this result:

```
600317422117
```

Comment: Hi, Please try as `LPAD(projectid,3,0) ||LPAD(disttid,3,0)|| to_char(max(cardno)+1)` .Hope this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the query as shown below and check.Hope this works.

```
select LPAD(projectid,3,'0')||LPAD(disttid,3,'0')||to_char(max(cardno)+1) "NEW_URN"
from we_group_hof_k 
where urn like '006%'
group by projectid,disttid;
```